# What causes the error "No certificate found in USB storage." when trying to import a certificate?

Tags: security, certificates

I have a Samsung S3 with Android 4.04 and to get on my WiFi at work I need to install a certificate .p12 file.  So, I navigate to "Security and lock screen"-->"Install from device storage."  BUT instead of giving me a field to specify the location of my cert ( on /mnt/extSdCard )  it just says "No certificate found in USB storage."

There are some USB devices ( called "UsbDriveA" through "UsbDriveF" in my /mnt folder) but I cannot copy the cert onto them because they are read-only.

So, how do I get this certificate imported?  I tried using "Android Certificate Installer" from the app store and that didn't work for me either: it launches a browser and the browser fails to prompt for the cert password.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a workaround.  The workaround is to download a File Manager tool and then double click the .p12 cert, which opens up and prompts for the password.   I still don't know why the control panel doesn't do what it suggests, but at least I found a solution.

Comment: If you don't know which file manager to use - I successfully applied the workaround via [OI File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.openintents.filemanager) - OI FIle Manager seems to be open-source and comes with sane permissions.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it wants the cert to be in a particular spot (and possibly to have a particular name).

From [Google's support pages](http://support.google.com/android/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1649774), we see that the cert has to be at the root of your phone's INTERNAL storage, not external.